# Changing the content with ajax on click on taxonomy category from dropdown list

Tags: ajax

I have a dropdown with Wordpress Taxonomy categories.Under it have a scroll area part with its posts from the taxonomy category how shown in the pic. [image: pic]How i can change the content with **Ajax** on dropdown category click for not refreshing the page and after it show content?
Havent used **Ajax** often and need help. Need to have some ajax code that will give me opprrtunity to call only one part of page with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a one solution like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".options li").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".news_cat_content").html("<div class='load' style='position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;'><img src='<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif'></div>");
        $(".news_cat_content").load(post_link);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```